# Change of variable method for non-homogenous linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

How do you find the particular solution using the change of variable $x = Ty$ where the first row of T is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$x'$ = $Ax + g(t)$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\4 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ $x$ + $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\0 \end{pmatrix}$

Can the method of diagonalization be used for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution of homogeneous equation is $x = \begin{pmatrix} \exp{4t} & 1\\2 \exp{4t}& -2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$. Try $x=\begin{pmatrix} \exp{4t} & 1\\2 \exp{4t}& -2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a(t)\\b(t)\end{pmatrix}$ to solve non-homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the general solution for first-order constant-coefficient linear DE with driving terms
$$
x'(t)=Ax(t)+g(t)
$$
is given by
$$
x(t)=\underbrace{\exp(A(t-t_0))x(t_0)}_{\text{soln to hgs eqn}}+\underbrace{\int_{t_0}^t\,\mathrm{d}\tau\exp(A(t-\tau))g(\tau)}_{\text{particular solution}}
$$
So you just have to compute the integral.

Comment: can the method of diagonalization be used instead?